# Calculate angle between two 3D points

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, geometry, 3d, angles

Given two points with xyz-coordinates, how to find the angle between them as shown in the picture. Is there a tool for it in ArcGIS Pro? I have looked into PointGeometry, but it did not seem to have anything for 3D points.

[image]

Comment: Are these points under 2D layers or 3D layers in Pro Scene? Did you try looking for the measure tool, although it's designed for measuring angles for 2D config?

Comment: Are the z values stored as a field in your attribute table? If so you can compute the horizontal distances then calculate the angle in a new field using inverse sine function of horizontal distance divided by hypotenuse length.

Comment: Why is this post closed? It is a valid question, this is a clear example of WHY many people have left this type of forums over the years.

Comment: @Gery  if you think the close vote is wrong then vote to reopen it. If you think that closing questions looking for code that don't show some effort (by showing what they have tried so far) is wrong then ask a question on meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PointGeometry](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/pointgeometry.htm) doesn't have have a direct method to return the vertical angle between two points, but it can by used in a Python script to deliver what you're after.  This example is verbose to demonstrate the calculations in some detail.  It could be streamlined and error trapping added for when the vertical distance is zero (i.e. vertical angle = 90 degrees) and test if the points are coincident.

This was tested in ArcMap but should work the same in ArcGIS Pro.

```
import arcpy
import math

# making the assumption that the points are in a projected coordinate system and
# that the measurement unit for horizontal and vertical are the same i.e. metres

# input feature layer must be points (Z-enabled) and only the first two will be used
# this code could be modified to process all points in a feature layer 
# if required (i.e. turn this into a function)
points = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# read in the point geometries into a list to make it easier for processing
pointGeometry = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points, ["SHAPE@"]) as aRows:
    for aRow in aRows:
        pointGeometry.append(aRow[0])

# create variables for the two points
point1 = pointGeometry[0]
point2 = pointGeometry[1]

# get the distance between the points     
horDistance = point1.angleAndDistanceTo(point2, "PLANAR")[1]

# calculate the vertical distance between the points
verDistance = point2.firstPoint.Z - point1.firstPoint.Z

# calculate the vertical angle
angle = math.acos(verDistance/horDistance) # the result is in radians
angleDeg = math.degrees(angle) # convert the angle to degrees

# output the results
arcpy.AddMessage("Horizontal distance Point 1 to 2: {}".format(horDistance))
arcpy.AddMessage("Vertical distance Point 1 to 2: {}".format(verDistance))
arcpy.AddMessage("Vertical angle (radians) Point 1 to 2: {}".format(angle))
arcpy.AddMessage("Vertical angle (degrees) Point 1 to 2: {}".format(angleDeg))
```

Example output:
[image]